# Distributing java web applications

Tags: java, web-applications, jboss, installation

We have a java application hosted on JBoss with a Posgres DB, and we've traditionally been selling it as an appliance (full server with application installed). Now, we need to allow clients to be able to download and install it on their servers. What is the best way to approach this? Ideally, I'd like it to be a one packaged installation file that they can run and it checks for dependencies, deploys the war file, executes the postgres sql to setup the database and start up jboss.

JBoss and Postgres will be installed by the client prior to installation.

The simplest way is to use a bash script for Linux and possible bat/cmd files for Windows, though that is not ideal. Are there any libraries available to accomplish something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

install4j can be used to let users install applications. The installation package will contain everything needed (application, JBoss, postgres). Furthermore, it has ant and maven tasks, too, and you can even allow the users to do some basic configuration on-the-fly.

Comment: A quick look at it gives me the impression that it's designed for Java applications with Java GUIs and not web applications. How would it work with jboss?

Comment: the same way how it would work with Tomcat. Principally, you can use it for any Java application. To use this with servers such as JBoss and Tomcat, you can have your application already deployed (not in a WAR file).

Comment: So the installer has an option where it will detect jboss installation and deploy it?

Comment: not that, but I mean you can distribute JBoss or Tomcat with it, which is much more comfortable.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of JBoss is OSGi based. Have you consider to use this solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If JBoss and Postgres are already preinstalled and configured by users as they wish then it would be very difficult to make a silver-bullet automatic installer that takes into account and correctly handles whatever incompatibilities it can face in real life.

Maybe a detailed install instruction would be enough. Especially for advanced users. For the others - bundle some diagnoctic scripts in case they face problem.

Also consider using [liquibase](http://www.liquibase.org/) to do automatic database initialization and migration on application's startup. This would greatly simplify the rest of install procedure: just check deps, make datasource and deploy app.